# Is Bitcoin still an experiment?

Tags: bitcoin-economy, adoption

Definition of the word *Experiment*:

> A scientific procedure undertaken to make a discovery, test a
>   hypothesis, or demonstrate a known fact.

If Bitcoin was/is an experiment, I don't think it's trying to make a discovery, it certainly isn't demonstrating a known fact.

It might be more closer to testing an hypothesis like "A digital decentralized form of money is viable". But what exactly is the hypothesis? Where does the test end? Who declares the end of the experiment? The bitcoin foundation? The governments? Forum folk?

As we're nearing the end of 2014 and getting closer to the fifth birthday of Bitcoin, is it still an experiment?

*I know that this is a very broad and open ended question. And yet, the argument is popularly used by prominent people from the community. Like Gavin Andresen. Everytime he faces a tough question, this is his response. If we don't know where the experiment began and where it ended or where it will end, then maybe we should not use this as a wildcard answer.*

Comment: Thanks George. I thought this question would receive more attention. Given that "bitcoin is an experiment/is experimental" is a commonly used "thing".

Comment: I would say that Bitcoin is [*experimental*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/experimental), which has a less strict meaning than *experiment*. Plenty of things are done in the real world that are meant to increase experience and knowledge, without (a) being an "experiment" in the sense you have quoted or (b) being a complete solution to a specific problem. Bitcoin is pretty clearly somewhere between those two extremes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is Bitcoin still an experiment?

I don't think so. There's no control, and nobody's made one of those [three panel boards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh6tt.jpg).

In all seriousness, though, I think Satoshi probably wrote and published Bitcoin because he found it interesting. He may also have done so because it aligned with his political views. Of course, we're speculating on the motives of a guy that nobody's met.

I also speculate that the current Bitcoin developers are part of the project for much the same reason.

> When does the test end? Who declares the end of the experiment?

Anybody could declare it, I suppose. It would be a bit like Emperor Norton ordering the US Army to arrest the United Nations, but they could still declare it.

> As we're nearing the end of 2014 and getting closer to the fifth birthday of Bitcoin, is it still an experiment?

I think the essence of your question is, "Is Bitcoin ready for mainstream adoption?" I don't think so. There's aren't mature payment solutions for physical stores. There are problems with Bitcoin that haven't been sufficiently solved to my mind (primarily detecting double spending).

Comment: being mainstream ready != not being an experiment & being beta != being an experiment. So the essence of my question is not about being ready for mainstream adoption.

Comment: @AntonA. what *is* your question getting at, if I can get you to clarify further?